# mysql-query number of rows for each day, based on given timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with 2 columns: `id` and `add_timestamp`. the user can select any arbitrary timestamp in the dashboard and then I have to query the number of rows that have been added in each day, over the past 30 days, **relative to the selected timestamp**

for example if the user has selected the timestamp `X` as the base, then (timestamps are in second):

`day 1` is from `X-1*24*60*60` to `X`

`day 2` is from `X-2*24*60*60` to `X-1*24*60*60`

and so on. how to query number of rows for each of these days (over the past 30 days)?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want, filtering with aggregation by day?

```
select date(add_timestamp), count(*)
from t
where add_timestamp >= ? - interval 30 day and
      add_timestamp < ?
group by date(add_timestamp);
```

`?` is a parameter placeholder for the timestamp selected by the user.

EDIT:

If you want this based on the *time* in the timestamp (i.e. 24 hours before each date), then you can subtract the time in the timestamp and extract the day:

```
select date(subtime(add_timestamp, time(?)) as dy, count(*)
from t
where add_timestamp >= ? - interval 30 day and
      add_timestamp < ?
group by dy;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. no! aggregation is not wanted, only the absolute count for each day

Comment: @Soheil . . . Huh?  This returns the count for each day.

Comment: the condition in `add_timestamp < ?` is constant and is the same for all days. right? so how this query works?!

Comment: @soheil . . . `add_timestamp` is a column in your table.  `?` is the parameter for the timestamp that you want to compare to.

Comment: I mean for day 1 the condition is `add_timestamp`<x, for day 2 the condition is `add_timestamp`<(x-24*60*60) and so on. so the value at the right side of condition is changing, but in `add_timestamp < ?`, the value of `?` is constant.

Comment: The value of `add_timestamp` is different for each record, and the value for `? - interval 30 day` is constant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your update. I just do not understand the condition `add_timestamp >= ? - interval 30 day and add_timestamp < ?` in which the `>= ? - interval 30 day` is changing for each day, but `< ?` is not. so how it works correctly?!

Comment: @Soheil . . . It is taking all timestamps from the 30 day period before the timestamp passed in.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it seems that `date(subtime(add_timestamp, time(?))` is wrong since `add_timestamp` and `?` are both in timestamp